# Elevating Powershell to admin and keeping passed arguments

Tags: powershell

### This was an unsuccessful attempt by me to explain the issue, please scroll down to see a hopefully better explanation

---

So I'm trying to have my script self-elevate itself to use admin rights.

I think I tried every fix possible on how to elevate a PS session to admin rights but it seems that none can make my arguments stick after the PS session re-opens. I'm assuming it's me who misunderstands how to do this properly.

I have a script that has only one parameter that can be passed to it. Here is the relevant block of code that includes the parameter in the script and the function that I call to elevate to admin permissions:

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][bool]$Param1= $false
)


function openWithPriv {
    if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)) {
        Start-Process PowerShell -Verb RunAs "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command `"cd '$pwd'; & '$PSCommandPath';`";`"$args`"";
        exit;
    }
}
```

When I run my script and add my parameter, it just skips that function all together. For example: `.\script.ps1 -Param1 $true` runs the script in its' entirety but when it reaches my function, it just goes to the `Default` switch:

```
function runParam1 {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][bool]$Param1= $false
    )
    switch ($Param1) {
        $true { 
            Write-Host "script works" 
         }
        Default {
            Write-Host "script didn't run" -ForegroundColor Red
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, here is how I call all of the functions in my script, maybe I'm doing something wrong here as well?

```
#Run all functions
try {
    openWithPriv
    runParam1 -Param1 $Param1
    someFunction1
    someFunction2
}
catch {
    Write-Host "Unknown error" -ForegroundColor Red -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Read-Host -Prompt "Press any key to continue"
}
```

What am I missing? Any help to fix this would be great :)

---

### This is another attempt to explain, with the full script

So here is my script:

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][bool]$param1 = $false
)

function openWithPriv {
    if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)) {
        Start-Process PowerShell -Verb RunAs "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command `"cd '$($PWD.Path)'; & '$PSCommandPath';`";`"$args`"";
        exit;
    }
}

function func1 {

    try {
        Write-Host "executing function number 1" -BackgroundColor Blue
    
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host "Unknown error in func1" -ForegroundColor Red -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
}

function func2 {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][bool]$param1 = $false
    )
    switch ($param1) {
        $true { 
            Write-Host "Executing function 2 because param1 was passed"
         }
        Default {
            Write-Host "Skipping func2 because param1 is false" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        }
    }
}

function func3{
    try {
        Write-Host "Executing function 3"
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host "Error, couldn't execute func3" -ForegroundColor Red -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
}

#Run all functions
try {
    openWithPriv
    func1
    func2 -param1 $param1
    func3
    Read-Host "Script finishd without an issue, press any key to exit"
}
catch {
    Write-Host "Unknown error somewhere in the script" -ForegroundColor Red -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Read-Host -Prompt "Press any key to continue"
}
```

#### The issue:

When I execute the script and give it the parameter, nothing happens, it just skips that function and goes to the default switch which is to just prompt the user that the function was skipped.

#### Example

When I run `.\test.ps1`, this is the output:

[image]

When I run `.\test.ps1 -param1 $true`

This is the output:

[image]

The output should include this text `Executing function 2 because param1 was passed` as it's shown in `func2`.

#### Bottom line

As you can see, because I elevate the script to use admin rights the parameter I'm passing is "lost" when it reaches that function.

Hope this was a bit more clear :)

Comment: Try to swap `$pwd` with `$($PWD.Path)`

Comment: @T-Me Thanks for the suggestion, seems like it still doesn't work. The script runs but the function is treated as if the parameter that is passed to it is `$false` so the output gives `script didn't run` still.

Comment: Is the try/catch in the switch or the switch in the try/catch?

Comment: @T-Me if you're referring to the `runParam1` function, there is no try/catch there. Not in the switch and not outside of it.

Comment: For my understanding: You have a script starting with `param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory...`. In that script is the `function openWithPriv`. In that function is a switch. You pass an argument to the script and the script passes the argument to the function. However the switch in the function does not get the arg. Is that correct? So the next question would be how does your script call the function

Comment: @T-Me I edited my post to show how my script runs the function. I just added a try catch at the end to call all of the functions. Also, in the `openWithPriv` function there is no try/catch.

Comment: could you add the whole `function openWithPriv` as it is in your script? In the first codeblock it contains `$args` in the `Start-Process` but there are no args passed to `Start-Process`. And if I understand corecctly the function contains a switch like the one in your second codeblock. That isn't shown in the function aswell.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228252/discussion-between-daniel-and-t-me).

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I think with all the code blocks you posted I cant seem to figure out exactly where your issue is.
Could you redo it so that I can copy / run it on my machine and still get the same issue? @Daniel

Comment: @ArcSet I edited my post with a better explanation and the full script, hopefully not it's better.

Comment: @Daniel  think i get it. Before i find a solution. IS this what you need....
If not admin powershell...open admin powershell and run the command with the same parameters ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I think you loos the `param1` when you start an other process. The `$Args` are not present and not passed to the script. I splited the code a little to make it clearer

```
Start-Process PowerShell -Verb RunAs "
    -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command `"
        cd '$pwd';
        & '$PSCommandPath';
        `";`"     # this is just the string ";"
        $args     # these $args are written after the script is executed
    `"
";
```

Instead you need to pass the `$param1` to the script:

```
Start-Process PowerShell -Verb RunAs "
    -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command `"
        cd '$pwd';
        & '$PSCommandPath' -param1 $param1
    `"
";
```

However since `$param1` is `[bool]` and will only accept `[bool]` you get an error because you are in a string and `$param1` will automically be cast to `[string]` = `True` instead of `$true`. To prevent this use 1 and 0 instead:

```
if ($param1){
    $Arg = 1
}else{
    $Arg = 0
}
...
    Start-Process PowerShell -Verb RunAs "-NoProfile -Noexit -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command `"cd '$($PWD.Path)'; & '$PSCommandPath' -param1 $Arg`"";
```

This could be shortened to:

```
$Arg = [int]$param1
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why, but just for the heck of it, I changed the `bool` to `int` only in the param of the script, not inside of the function, and for some reason it works... So the param outside is `int` and the one inside is `bool` and when I call the function with the desired parameter, it actually works. I don't know how but hey, I'll take it. Thank you!

Comment: Daniel, it works because the Int in the outter routine will get cast properly to a Bool in the inner routine. Remember that when casting from Int to Bool 0 = False anything else = True including negative numbers!

Comment: @Daniel The last part was meant the other way round. `[int]$true` is allway `1` and `[int]$false` is allways `0`. And `[bool]1` is `$true` and `[bool]0` is `$false`. As @RetiredGeek wrote any other number is true too.

Comment: @RetiredGeek thank you! Thank you T-Me as well, much appreciated